# Transposing a Matrix in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have written the following code below to transpose a Matrix in prolog

```
listFirst([],[]).
listFirst([H1|T1],[H2|Z]):-
    H1 = [H2|_],
    listFirst(T1,Z).

listFollowers([],[]).
listFollowers([H1|T1],[T2|Z]):-
    H1 = [H2|T2],
    listFollowers(T1,Z).

decompose(A,L1,L2):-
    listFollowers(A,L2),listFirst(A,L1).

transpose([],[]).
transpose([H|T],[L1|R]):-   
    decompose([H|T],L1,L2),
    transpose(L2,R).
```

Test Case

```
transpose([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], R).
R = [[1,3,5],[2,4,6]] ;
```

I am having problems with the transpose predicate no sure how to implement this. Other predicates seem to work okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help.
If you change the base case in order to have the lists of lists to a complete list it will work. Even though it probably won`t be the most efficient method, since it will only be able to get up to 4 lists. This means a matrix of four rows.

```
transpose([[X],[Y],[Z],[B]],[[X,Y,Z,B]]).
transpose([H|T],[L1|R]):-    
    decompose([H|T],L1,L2),
    transpose(L2,R).
```

Answer (score 3):

Taken from `library(clpfd)` in SWI-Prolog (see the [source code](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/blob/80cfdbf0bfc61f90aeb0e11f74496a1e6704e14a/library/clp/clpfd.pl#L6375-L6385) for more information):

```
transpose([], []).
transpose([L|Ls], Ts) :- foldl(transpose_, L, Ts, [L|Ls], _).

transpose_(_, Fs, Lists0, Lists) :-
        maplist(list_first_rest, Lists0, Fs, Lists).

list_first_rest([L|Ls], L, Ls).
```

Example query:

```
?- transpose([[a,b,c],[d,e,f]], Ts).
Ts = [[a, d], [b, e], [c, f]].
```

Answer (score 3):

my old code - rather efficient tough

```
transpose_col_row([], []).
transpose_col_row([U], B) :- gen(U, B).
transpose_col_row([H|T], R) :- transpose_col_row(T, TC), splash(H, TC, R).

gen([H|T], [[H]|RT]) :- gen(T,RT).
gen([], []).

splash([], [], []).
splash([H|T], [R|K], [[H|R]|U]) :-
    splash(T,K,U).
```